# Don't we have region specific data center for Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I could see only United States as the option for visual studio online.
Do we have another alternative: East Asia / South East Asia?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you do not get to choose a US datacenter. We originally had everything in North Central. We have another scale unit in South Central, and we have closed North Central to new accounts (it's just too large). Those are the only two right now. At some point, we will have more and may allow you to choose.